# A variable for user ID, reachable during the whole process of page creation.(instead of session)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently using session to hold the user ID at my web application. And i read a lot about sessions is evil, so my plans is to find another solution.

So my next step is to use encrypted cookie.
Something like:

```
userInformation: ENCRYPT(UserID,subdomain,someComputerUniqueValue,hashvalueOftheString)
```

each user has their own subdomain, so the UserID and Subdomain must match.
But. Now at almost every page i call the session value to get the userID.
I want to change this to some kind of variable, but what kind of variable?!
I am now setting the session value inside a httpmodule. in the

```
public void Application_PreBeginRequest
```

Is it possible to create a variable within application_prebeginRequest and read it somewhere else during the creation of the page. for example in the masterpage, och the contentpage. or the classes that is used at that specific page.
WHen the page is created and sent to the client, the variable should die.

What kind of variable am i looking for? is it global variable? if not, what is global variable?

Thanks for reading!
Mattias R.

Edit:

This cookie is not for authentication. I want to save the ID of the user connected to the subdomain, so i dont have to run the "SELECT ID from account where subdomain='somethin'" query each time a page is visited.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the session for this?

Comment: i've read a lot of bad stuff about sessions. And i want to learn more of asp.net.

Comment: Session is not "evil". Maybe you didn't understand what you read.

Comment: I think that i understood what i read.. So, Am i wrong about this? There is a lot of articles on the internet saying that sessions are not as good as you think.

Comment: I guess the "problem" with sessions is when you use them in a web farm environment (with in-process storage). People start using one server, their information are kept on sessions, and when their requests eventually go to another server, the web app can't find the data. But I think sessions aren't evil when used in a proper way and in the right scenario. []'s

Comment: I do not think they are so bad either, but since you can read negative about them, I can already at an early stage deselect them if possible. And so it is interesting to learn new things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store what you need inside the HttpContext.Current.Items. Items put inside that will live only during the current web request and will be available globally in your web application.

```
// Global.asax
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Items["hello"] = DateTime.Now;
}
// Default.aspx
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = HttpContext.Current.Items["hello"].ToString();
    }
}
```

By the way, at Application_BeginRequest event, the Session object isn't available.

For more information about HttpContext.Current.Items, look at https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please provide why this answer does not fit the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Mattias, but it would be nice to know why my answer was not correct, so I can improve myself on my next answers. []'s

Comment: The downvote was mine, and I think it must have been an accident. I don't downvote unless I say why. [so] won't let me remove the downvote unless you edit the answer. Please edit the answer and reply to this comment and I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Once the user is authenticated, why don't you log them in with [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx)?

You can then retrieve the currently logged in user using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.

Comment: Im going to take a look at that method. But it is actually not a authentication i am looking for. I want to use this cookie save the ID of the user connected to that subdomain. So i dont have to get the ID from database each time a page is created.

Comment: You can provide whatever identifier you want to SetAuthCookie, as long as it is convertable to a string and is unique among your users, so there would be no problem using your userid.

Answer (score 0):

Session is not "evil" Session is stored on the server, and for small amounts of data such as what you suggest, it scales very well.

Comment: Okay. I store only ID of accountID, userID and adminID, 3 ints. And even if i dont use for example userID and adminID, i've heard that the memory usage is the same, as if each visitor use all three values. is this true? So just to get some more understanding. lets say i use 3 ints in my session variables, and there are 100,000 visitors, how many MB of memory does my session object use?